# Can cross join work with window function like - row_number() function

Tags: sql-server

Window function can not be used in where clause. In the below query rn column can be used in where clause only in the outer query like -

```
select * from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as rn 
from tab1) as abc
where rn = 1
```

can we use rn column with cross join some thing like -

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as rn 
from tab1 as a
cross join(select rn from a)

Just curious to know as i am trying to learn SQL server
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in this way. You either have to repeat `ROW_NUMBER()` inside the subquery:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS rn 
FROM tab1 AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS rn FROM tab1) t
```

or, alternatively, use a *common table expression*:

```
;WITH a AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS rn 
   FROM tab1
)
SELECT *
FROM a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT rn FROM a) t
```